# player.getCurrentTime() stopped working

Tags: javascript, video, timer, youtube

I have a project where I have an array of time stamps pausing an embedded video at set locations. 
This was working perfectly fine about a month ago, but have now stopped working without any changes to the code begin made.

Testing the code, I know that I can no longer access player.getCurrentTime().

Anyone know why this might have stopped working?

```
function timerCount() {  

current_time = Math.round(player.getCurrentTime()*10)/10;

timer = setTimeout("timerCount()", 100);
document.getElementById('CT').innerHTML = current_time; 
if(sign == true){ 
      for(var j = 1; j < videoTS[inp_idx].length; j++){
          if(current_time == videoTS[inp_idx][j] && autoStop == true){
              pauseVideo();
          }
      }
}else{ 
      for(var j = 1; j < video[inp_idx].length; j++){
      if(current_time == video[inp_idx][j] && autoStop == true){

          pauseVideo();
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Stripping down the code to bare essentials still doesn't have the getCurrentTime working...

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: 'EG3Nh19wE4I',
events: {
  'onStateChange': loadVideo
}
});
}


var current_time;

function loadVideo(id){


newID = "//www.youtube.com/embed/"+id;
var player = document.getElementById('player');
document.getElementById('player').src = newID; 
current_time = player.getCurrentTime();
document.getElementById('CT').innerHTML = current_time; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to it. I don't know why it stopped working, but I wasn't using the iframe generated by the JavaScript, but a HTML generated one. Once I changed to only using the one generated by the JavaScript, it works. I now have trouble with getting the video on mobile devices as they won't allow auto play. But that's a different matter..